# Angular 2 - Get one property of object into array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following object

```
export class HourPerMonth {
    constructor(
        public year_month: string,
        public hours: string,
        public amount: string
    ) { };
}
```

Now i want to fill an array with only the hours from the object.

```
private hourPerMonth: HourPerMonth[];
private hoursArray: Array<any>;

getChartData() {
    this.chartService.getHoursPerMonth().subscribe(source => {
        this.hourPerMonth = source;
        this.hoursArray = ?
    });
}
```

How do i get the hours from the object into the hoursArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
this.hoursArray = source.map(obj => obj.hours);
```

Also it can be:

```
private hoursArray: Array<string>;
```

Or simply:

```
private hoursArray: string[];
```

Answer (score 0):

This way should work for you.

```
private hourPerMonth: HourPerMonth[];
private hoursArray: Array<any> = [];

getChartData() {
   this.chartService.getHoursPerMonth().subscribe(source => {
       this.hourPerMonth = source;
       this.hourPerMonth.forEach(hourPerMonth => {
          this.hoursArray.push(hourPerMonth.hours);
       }
   });
}
```